# Find for all those records having same Last Name and same Postcode

Tags: sql, postal-code

I need a SQL script to find for all those records in a database having the same Last Name and the same Postcode

For example:

```
first_Name   Last_Name  Postcode
Nathan       Yorke      SY3 0NN
Calum        Yorke      SY3 0NN
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's your DBMS? Does it support `COUNT() OVER`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by last_name, postcode) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```